# Instagram API - Get newest posts same with user Instagram wall

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there any API that allow me get the newest posts same with what is displayed in the user Instagram wall?

I looked the API document, and just found the endpoint for get feed of a specify user only. I want to get the list of photos/videos that is merged from multiple user feed who the current user has followed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed API existed before, but was stopped after June 1, 2016. Probably because they want all people to use Instagram app for viewing that feed, that way Instagram can sell Ads and make money.

Comment: Yep, I found that api has been deprecated. Thanks